# Why did EVAL-WHEN with :LOAD-TOPLEVEL not run the body when I LOAD the file?

Tags: common-lisp

I have written this Lisp program:

```lisp
(eval-when (:load-toplevel)
  (princ "Hello!"))
```

However, when I load the program, the body of the `eval-when` is not run.

```
$ sbcl
* (load "hello.lisp")
T
*
```

What is happening? In the `eval-when`, I used `:load-toplevel` to specify that its body should be run when I load the file. I am surprised that `(princ "Hello!")` did not run when I loaded the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [CLHS](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_eval_w.htm):

> The use of the situations `:compile-toplevel` (or `compile`) and `:load-toplevel` (or `load`) controls whether and when evaluation occurs when `eval-when` appears as a top level form in code processed by `compile-file`.

Since you're not loading the compiled file, the `:load-toplevel` situation doesn't apply. Use `:execute` to execute code when the source is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the answer by user "Barmar" for the HyperSpec reference.

When the file is compiled using `compile-file`, `:load-toplevel` instructs the compiler to arrange for the body of the `eval-when` to be run when the compiled program is `load`ed.

Therefore, to run the body of the `eval-when` in the OP's example, first compile the file, then load the fasl file that is produced:

```
$ sbcl
* (compile-file "hello.lisp")
; compiling file "/home/user/programs/hello.lisp" (written 16 APR 2022 12:34:56 PM):

; wrote /home/user/programs/hello.fasl
; compilation finished in 0:00:00.003
#P"/home/user/programs/hello.fasl"
NIL
NIL
* (load "hello.fasl")
Hello!
T
*
```